# Vapor - How to increase Size of folder for deploying to staging and production?

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, server, forge, laravel-vapor

I try to deploy our code to staging I was found an error message something like this.

> Compressed application is greater than 45MB. Your application is 69
> MB. Whoops! There were some problems with your request. Vapor
> applications may not have more than 300 public assets.

Very small ????? It's not enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like Taylor just launched the solution to this problem. You need to update your `vapor-core` and `vapor-cli` packages to the latest version. Then add `separate-vendor: true` to your `Vapor.yml` file. Details here: https://blog.laravel.com/vapor-reusable-vendors

Comment: Even then if you have more than 300 assets, it means one has to manually copy the files to the bucket and disclude them from getting pushed to github during the CI.

Comment: Note that this option has since been deprecated, and Docker based deployments are the recommended option: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#runtime

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to switch to the docker runtime:

> Application Size
>
> AWS Lambda has strict limitations on the size of applications running
> within the environment. If your application exceeds this limit, you
> may take advantage of Vapor's Docker based deployments. Docker based
> deployments allow you to package and deploy applications up to 10GB in
> size.

The Vapor docs link to https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#building-custom-docker-images wihch seems to be broken or pointing to an old documentation structure.

I think the correct link to the docs about the docker runtime is here: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#docker-runtimes

You should probably try this in a new environment because once you switch an environment to docker you can't switch back to the default vapor runtime for some reason. So just try the docker runtime in test environment by passing the `--docker` flag:

```
vapor env docker-test --docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The `separate-vendor` option is deprecated now. Instead use Docker Runtimes: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#runtime

Create a `production.Dockerfile` file in your project root with these contents:

```
FROM laravelphp/vapor:php82-arm

COPY . /var/task
```

Then update your `vapor.yml` file to include the docker arm runtime:

```
# Arm
id: 2
name: vapor-laravel-app
environments:
    production:
        runtime: docker-arm
        build:
            - 'composer install --no-dev'
```